# Display an image stored inside a variable from an array in php

Tags: php

I am quite a novice and I am trying to display an image from an array and after many attempts I have not succeeded. Help!

```
  // Delivery.
 $barcode = '<img src="https://example.com/image/example.jpg" alt="">';

 $wyz_cmb_businesses->add_field(
   array(
    'name' => esc_html__( 'delivery', 'wyzi-business-finder' ),
    'id' => $prefix . 'business_delivery',
    'type' => 'multicheck',
    'default_cb' => 'propio',
    'options' => array( 'Propio' => $barcode, 'Uber' => esc_html__( 'Uber', 'wyzi-business-finder' ), 'Muv' => esc_html__( 'Muv', 'wyzi-business-finder' ), 'Pedidos ya' => esc_html__( 'Pedidos ya', 'wyzi-business-finder' ) ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'class' => 'wyz-select',
     ),
  ) 
);
```

Admin
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnCxL.jpg)

Client side code

```
<?php if ( '' !== $business_data['delivery'] ) {?>

                <?php echo esc_url( $business_data['delivery'] );?><i class="fa fa-globe" aria- 
            hidden="true"></i> <?php print_r ( $business_data['Propio'] ); echo"\n"; ?>  <?php 
           print_r ( $business_data['Uber'] ); echo"\n"; ?> <?php print_r ( $business_data['Muv'] );

                foreach($business_data['delivery'] as $value)
                { 
                echo $value . "<br />\n";
                }
               ?>

            <?php }?>
```

[Obtained result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm8Du.jpg)

Comment: Try Replacing `$business_data['Propio'] ` with `$business_data['options']['Propio'] `

Comment: i tried but it didn't work

Comment: Actually, what `$business_data` contains? Can you update the question with Printing that variable?